# SwiftUI - Display the views marked as favorites in a list

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui, state, favorites

Just in case, the Book struct is below.

```
struct Book: Identifiable {
var id = UUID().uuidString
var title: String
var description: String
var imageURL: URL
var sourceOfDesc: String
var descSourceCitation: String
}
```

My goal is to display a list of BookDetailView marked as favorites. A class to add and remove books from the favorites has been created.

```
class Favorites: ObservableObject {
// The actual books the user marked as favorite.
@Published var books: [String]

// The key to be used to read/write in the UserDefaults
private let saveKey = "Favorites"

init() {
    // Load saved data
    books = []
}

// Returns true if the set contains this book
func contains(_ book: Book) -> Bool {
    books.contains(book.id)
}

func add(_ book: Book) {
    objectWillChange.send()
    books.insert(book.id, at: 0)
    save()
}

func remove(_ book: Book) {
    objectWillChange.send()
    books.removeAll { $0 == book.id }
    save()
}

func save() {
    // Write data
  }
}
```

Updated FavoritesView below.

```
struct FavoritesView: View {
@ObservedObject var favoriteList: Favorites
var book: Book

var body: some View {
    List(favoriteList.books) { book in
        NavigationLink {
            WorksListTemplateView(books: book)
        } label: {
            Text(book.title)
        }
     }
   }
}
```

I get multiple error messages on FavoritesView, the ones that jump out to me are these 2:

1. Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Binding'
2. Generic parameter 'Data' could not be inferred

Comment: 2 remarks : books should be a @Published var, so you do not call object will change ; worddlisttemplateview : you pass a book to a parameter named bookS ?

Comment: Also : how is declared Favorites ? It sometime a var, sometime environment object. it should be declared as @StateObect at first. BTW, once a var is declared as environment object of a view, it is automatically set as this in all sub views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List` is excepting a `RandomAccessCollection`, `Set` doesn't not conform to it. So you should convert your set to an array: `Array(favoritesList.books)`.

However, since `String` does not conform to `Identifiable`, you also need to add an id to the list:

```
 List(Array(favoritesList.books), id: \.self) { book in
```

### **Remarks**:

1. As mentioned in the comments, in `Favorites` you should mark books using `@Published` in order for `ObservableObject` to take effect:

   ```
   @Published var books: Set<String> //or an array [String]
   ```
2. In `FavoritesView`, favoriteList should be:

   ```
   @ObservedObject var favoriteList: Favorites 
   //ObservedObject & not StateObject because the object is passed 
   //down from another View & not directly initialized in the View.
   ```
3. In `BookDetailView`, you don't need `.environmentObject(favorites)`. You inject it when you first Initialize it, i.e where you don't have `@EnvironmentObject var favorites: Favorites` or when you are presenting another `View` that needs it.
4. Also in `BookDetailView`, if you need to mutate book from its `View` mark it with `@State`. If you need to mutate book from another `View`, in that `View` mark it with `@Binding`.

Comment: Ptit Xav, thank you for the remarks! @NoeOnJupiter Thank you for the extended explanation!! I will take all of this into account and change my code. Will get back with the results of the changes I make.

Comment: I have implemented the changes mentioned above. I am still getting the following on FavoritesView =  1. Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Binding<Data>'

Comment: Hi! First the compiler is confused as to what book to use since you have 2. In the `NavigationLink` label, `book.title` do you mean the book property? If so all the cells will have the same title then. `String` does not conform to `Identifiable` so you need to add the id, check out the `List` in my answer for more info.